# Qt Compile error from moc file, issue arising from changing name of a widget

Tags: c++, qt5, moc

So I added a slider into a UI Form, and I clicked go to slot -> sliderReleased()..no problem there. BUT, then after having done that, I changed slider name from default of `horizontalSlider` to `slider1` and deleted the old null implementation Qt had made. Now when I try to build my project I get this error:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-PROJECT_KART-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-
Debug\debug\moc_minigame2.cpp:94: error: undefined reference to 
`Minigame2::on_horizontalSlider_2_sliderReleased()'
```

So what, it thinks that slot should still be there? How do I fix this?

Comment: I would try a clean build.

Comment: I have tried cleaning and rebuilding from build menu, but there is no change. Same compile errors.

Comment: So you do not have on_horizontalSlider_2_sliderReleased() in your header?

Comment: Oh damn it all! >.< ...The prototypes were still in the header >__> that's probably the entirety of the problem.